# Android Activities issue

Tags: android, android-activity

I have strange problem with transition from one to another activity. Actually when I try to navigate to the willing activity the app crashes and the current activity is restarted. Here is some code:

```
    // Home Activity
    Intent intent = new Intent(Home.this, News.class);
    intent.putExtra("category", categories[currentCategory]);
    intent.putExtra("newstext", (rssList.get(position)).getData());
    startActivity(intent);
```

This is a source-code from **News Activity**:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(FLAG_FULLSCREEN, FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.news);

        savedInstanceState = getIntent().getExtras();

        String category = savedInstanceState.getString("category");
        String newstext = savedInstanceState.getString("newstext");

        activeCategory = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.hActiveCategory);
        activeCategory.setText(category);

        returnBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Return);
        returnBtn.setOnClickListener(returnClick);

        String encoding = getResources().getString(R.string.encoding);
        String mimeType = getResources().getString(R.string.mimetype);
        wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.WebView);
        wv.loadData(newstext, mimeType, encoding);
    }
```

It works properly only when I'm testing it with **AVD emulator**.

[LogCat from AVD emulator](http://pastebin.com/7KBUx31s).

These two lines are from **CogCat** when I navigate to **News Activity**:

```
07-12 16:41:35.431: I/ActivityManager(292): START u0 {cmp=com.rss.reader/.News (has extras)} from pid 4741
07-12 16:41:35.910: I/ActivityManager(292): Displayed com.rss.reader/.News: +452ms
```

Comment: What is the error in LogCat?

Comment: OK, now there is it but just from AVD.

Comment: It would be quite easier, if you only post the stack trace from the error and not a huge output from logcat.

Comment: It works correctly on AVD, but it's crushing on my phone and I don't have error log from my phone. I'm not able to see what is causing the error.

Comment: I'm gonna throw out a guess that you're not passing the right values via your intent based on     intent.putExtra("category", categories[currentCategory]) on the sending end and String category = savedInstanceState.getString("category");
on the recieving end

Comment: @Rarw: ..but it works with the AVD emulator and I've debugged it to see what are the actual values that are passed and the data is passed correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem. It's not related to my development. It is related to phone settings. My phone was set to destroy all activities after the user leaves them, so when I've disabled this feature the app works just fine!

Thanks anyway to everyone!

Comment: Please accept this answer, so that the question doesn't show up on the list of questions without an accepted answer.